# Java Jena SPARQL doesn't show the desired result

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, sparql, jena

I got problem using the Jena and SPARQL when i was querying from my own RDF. I got the example from [this](https://tutorial-academy.com/full-text-search-sparql-lucene/). Here is my query codes:

```
 public static void queryData( Dataset dataset )
{
    System.out.println("Query data...") ;

    String prefix = "PREFIX cs: <" + URI + "> " + 
                    "PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#> ";

    String query = "SELECT * WHERE " +
           "{ ?informatika text:query (cs:hasBranch 'sistem') ." +
            "?informatika cs:hasBranch ?konsentrasi."+
           " }"; 

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() ;

    dataset.begin( ReadWrite.READ ) ;
    try 
    {
        Query q = QueryFactory.create( prefix + query );
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create( q , dataset );
        QueryExecUtils.executeQuery( q, qexec );
    }
    finally 
    {
        dataset.end() ; 
    }
```

And this is my RDF that i included in my codes (OntologyCS2.rdf):

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:cs="http://www.semanticweb.org/ulfaamalia/ontologies/2020/1/OntologyCS#" >
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ulfaamalia/ontologies/2020/1/OntologyCS#Informatika">
    <cs:hasBranch>Sistem Informasi</cs:hasBranch>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ulfaamalia/ontologies/2020/1/OntologyCS#Informatika">
    <cs:hasBranch>Rekayasa Perangkat Lunak</cs:hasBranch>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ulfaamalia/ontologies/2020/1/OntologyCS#Informatika">
    <cs:hasBranch>Jaringan dan Keamanan Komputer</cs:hasBranch>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ulfaamalia/ontologies/2020/1/OntologyCS#Informatika">
    <cs:hasBranch>Komputasi dan Sistem Cerdas</cs:hasBranch>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ulfaamalia/ontologies/2020/1/OntologyCS#Informatika">
    <cs:hasBranch>Informatika Medis</cs:hasBranch>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ulfaamalia/ontologies/2020/1/OntologyCS#Informatika">
    <cs:hasBranch>Multimedia Visi Komputer</cs:hasBranch>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

That query should appear "Sistem Informasi" only. But, the result showed this:

[image]

What's wrong about that? I hope you can read my explanation clearly. Please advise me. Thank you

Comment: what exactly is the question now? You have a dataset where a single individual has multiple `hasBranch` values. Your query does exactly what it does, it finds all individuals which have a branch matching the string "sistem'' and then via the second triple pattern get all branches for those individuals.

Comment: if you just want the branch literals, do `select ?konsentrasi where { (?s ?score ?konsentrasi) text:query (cs:hasBranch 'sistem') }`

Comment: @UninformedUser thank you for the answer and edited my question. I did the query you suggest but it got error. It says `Encountered " <STRING_LITERAL1> "\'sistem\' "" at line 1, column 205.`

Comment: I can't see the problem here. Can you try `select ?konsentrasi where { (?s ?score ?konsentrasi) text:query (cs:hasBranch "sistem") }` please? This is the correct syntax.

Comment: @UninformedUser what is the function of "score" by the way? I've tried it but unfortunately it can't work.  It shows error like my comment above. Oh ya, i can't use " " so i use ' ' instead.

Comment: which version of Jena do you use? This has to work and is the correct syntax.`?score` is the binding of the Lucene score. The syntax is `(?s ?score ?literal) text:query 'word'` where `?literal` is binding the literal value, which is what you wanted. And why should you not be able to use " " ?

Comment: @UninformedUser i'm using Jena 3.9.0 and Lucene 6.4.0. When i use " ", it turned red in my code bcs i have used " " when i wrote `String query = "SELECT... "` and so on. So i input the word using ' '.

Comment: `Jena 3.9.0` why a 2018 version, I don't get this always.  Obviously, syntax might have been extended in the meantime, I'd update to latest version which is 3.14.0

Comment: @UninformedUser i choose that bcs i follow the example: https://tutorial-academy.com/full-text-search-sparql-lucene/ maybe i should try 3.14 version

Comment: @UninformedUser by the way, what Lucene's version do you use?

Comment: Examples are mostly never updated. Usually, it's better to use the latest versions. Lucene `7.4.0` is used in latest Jena